# Using a compiled python regex pattern in a case unsensitive comparison

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have:

```
reYada = re.compile(u'^yAdA$', re.U)
```

At some point I need to perform a case insensitive comparison using this compiled pattern. I did it as:

```
re.match(reYada.pattern, 'yada', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Is there a way to do the same without `.pattern` (ie using the compiled pattern) ?

Comment: Looking at the API, I don't think this is possible. The possibility depends a lot on how the pattern is compiled, and allowing the option to change the behavior may bloat the size of the compiled code.

Comment: it would be `reYada.match` , not `re.match` and you can't modify the compiled pattern.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Not sure what you are talking about. https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match There is no parameter for you to put the flag in. `re.match` is actually the correct code here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match

Comment: yep, it's not possible.

Comment: @nhahtdh: so not possible then ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: I think so. If there is no API, then it's not possible.

Comment: @nhahtdh: what I meant is that a minimal rundown of the API with links could be answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the API of Regular Expression Object ([Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.RegexObject), [Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects)), which is the class of compiled regex object returned by `re.compile`, none of the methods allows you to specify the flag. The `flags` attribute is also read-only.

Therefore, it's not possible to change the flags of a compiled regex object. The method you have in the question, where you extract the pattern and recompile it with a new flag, is the way to go about it.

Allowing to change the behavior of a compiled regex by changing flags requires the compiled object to include the code path for different (combination of) flags, which will more or less (depending on the effect of the flag) bloat the compiled regex with unused code paths for most of the use cases.